# Typing in Chinese with a Dvorak layout

Tags: keyboard-layout, input-language, dvorak

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, and have Pinyin working as an input. However, I use the Dvorak layout and haven't been able to find a way to input Pinyin using the Dvorak layout - it defaults to QWERTY. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem until maybe 10 minutes ago. The way I solved this was to get rid of all keyboards layouts on the system except for EN-Dvorak and Pinyin.

This seems to solve the problem since ibus on pinyin mode specifies the default keyboard layout used on the system in "/usr/share/ibus/component/pinyin.xml"

```
<engine>
...
<layout>default</layout>
...
</engine>
```

If it can't find anything else other the dvorak then it is the default. I'm going to try adding EN-US back in now and see if it keeps dvorak as the default.

Comment: another option is to to just edit the EN-US keyboard files to match dvorak

Answer (score 0):

go to "`/usr/share/ibus/component/`" locate your dvorak layout (should be called something like `en-dvorak.xml`) and find the line that says

`<layout>...</layout>` (it won't have those dots instead it should have what ibus references a dvorak layout as)

Copy what the layout is called then locate the `pinyin.xml` and locate the line

`<layout>default</layout>` then remove the word "default" and put in what you got from the dvorak layout.

Your ibus should now point to dvorak rather than qwerty.